# ¿Cómo ordenar un array de objetos en typescrip y angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

estoy trabajando en una api con angular, y tengo el siguiente codigo en mi archivo ts.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';
import { Escuderia } from '../modelos/api.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-api-escuderias',
  templateUrl: './api-escuderias.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./api-escuderias.component.css']
})
export class ApiEscuderiasComponent implements OnInit {

  datosApi: Escuderia []= [];

  opcionSelecionada = "Escuderias";
  
  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {    
    this.obtenerDatos();  
     
  } 

  obtenerDatos(){

    this.apiService.getDatos().subscribe(data =>{
      this.datosApi= data;
      console.log(this.datosApi);      
                  
    }, error =>{
      console.log(error);
      
    })
    
  }

}
```

Lo que intento hacer, es lo que esta en el array 'datosApi', ordenarlo en un array nuevo por el valor de la clave 'campeonatos' de ese array. para mostrarlo con un *ngFor.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenté de la siguiente manera

```
datosC = this.datosApi.sort((a, b)=>{
    return (a.campeonatos - b.campeonatos)
});
```

Sencillamente me devuelve el array vacio, como se puede ver en la imagen de arriba. Si deseo mostrarlo por consola ordenadamente, igual sale vacio. Trate de recorrerlo con un forEach y tampoco, trate de asignarle un valor de la siguiente forma:

```
datosC = this.datosApi[0];
```

Me da errores, definitivamente no se como proceder, les agrdezco mucho saber porque el metodo sort no me está funcionando.

Comment: ¿En qué parte estás colocando el código de ordenamiento?

Comment: lo puse debajo de datosApi, tambien probe en el ngOnInit, probe en la funcion obtenerDatos, en todo lado.

Comment: ¿Cuales son los errores?

Comment: antes de suscribirte puedes hacer un .pipe o en el subscribe cuando obtienes la data puedes hacer el sort

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es crear un pipe para ordenar el array en el front

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'sort',
  pure: true,
})
export class SortPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform<T>(array: Array<T>, args: string): Array<T> {
    return array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      if (a[args].toLowerCase() < b[args].toLowerCase()) {
        return -1;
      } else if (a[args] > b[args]) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

ya lo puedes usar en cualquier parte para ordenar arrays, entonces en el html lo que haces es:

```
<div *ngFor="let client of data| sort:'campeonatos'"</div>
```

le pasas sort:'campeonatos' ahi se ordena por campeonatos

tambien puedes probar lo siguiente:

```
obtenerDatos(){
  this.apiService.getDatos().pipe(map(value => value.sort((a,b) => {
    if (a.campeonatos < b.campeonatos){
      return -1
    }
  }))).subscribe(data =>{
    this.datosApi= data;
    console.log(this.datosApi);
  }, error =>{
    console.log(error);

  })

}
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, pero ninguna de las dos funciono, el pipe me daba error de "toLowerCase is not a function" y la función daba error con el map.

Comment: en el pipe elimina el toLowerCase, ya que ordenaras por numero, por lo tanto un numero no se puede poner en mayuscula ni en minuscula